# Configurar compilación en Angular para generar archivos main.js, polyfills.js sin texto adicional en el nombre "main-es5.d569c370b0a70b3ec537.js"

Tags: angular, configuración

estoy usando angular 9 y al compilar usando: ng build --prod
genera los archivos compilados incluyendo una cadena de caracteres antes de la extesión, ejemplo:

- main-es5.d569c370b0a70b3ec537.js
- polyfills-es5.07e229a2324577586988.js
- runtime-es5.17457c14269340561f33.js

necesito configurarlo para que los archivos se generen de esta forma:

- main.js
- polyfills.js
- runtime.js

Espero me puedan indicar en donde modificar la configuración para obtener ese resultado.
Se agraedece la ayuda.

Comment: Prueba con `ng build --prod --output-hashing none`

Comment: Funcionó !! Gracias Pablo por tu ayuda.